# How to cast void * to float (*)[3] in c++?

Tags: c++, casting

This is the code snippet.

```
typedef struct Lib3dsMesh {
 //..
 float (*vertices)[3]; 
 //..
}


void* lib3ds_util_realloc_array(void *ptr, int old_size, int new_size, int  element_size) {
    // Do something here.
    return ptr;
}


mesh->vertices = lib3ds_util_realloc_array(mesh->vertices, mesh->nvertices, nvertices, 3 * sizeof(float));
```

When I compile this code in visual c++ it returns error "Cannot convert from void* to float(*)[3]".

I would like to know how to cast void * to float (*vertices)[3];

Comment: Cast it like you cast anything else. At present you are not casting (explicit conversion) but relying on _implicit conversion_ (where none exists).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`vertices` is a [pointer to a 3-element array of `float`](http://cdecl.ridiculousfish.com/?q=+float+%28*vertices%29%5B3%5D). To do a cast from one pointer type to another, you generally use `static_cast`:

```
void* result = lib3ds_util_realloc_array(
    mesh->vertices, mesh->nvertices, nvertices, 3 * sizeof(float));
mesh-vertices = static_cast<float (*)[3]>(result);
```